# Need to relaunch app after logout to create new managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, appdelegate

I have an iOS app that uses CoreData to persist data retrieved from a server via RestKit.  I have created a logout button that clears all `NSUserDefaults` when pressed and sends the user back to the login screen.

When the app launches for the first time the `managedObjectStore` and all other CoreData features are generated in the `appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of the `appDelegate`.  However when I logout of the app and try to log back in an exception is thrown because my `managedObjectContext` is nil.  It is nil because I chose not to pass it from the logout viewController to the login viewController.  I want to clear out the old and create new for the new user.

I would like to create a new `managedObjectStore/Context` when I hit logout and move to the log in screen.  Is something like this possible?  Basically I need to relaunch the app when the user presses logout.

Could someone show me how something like this might be done?  I am pretty new at this so if this is inappropriate or unnecessary I'm open to learn the correct/appropriate way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relaunching the app is very bad practice as far as the Human Interface guidelines are concerned. Avoid this at all cost.

Try creating the data instances in a didLogin method, the login view controller can call this from the delegate if you like.

Otherwise, you can have the managedObjectStore be set to nil when you logout, and have an accessor method for it like so:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *_sharedInstance;
-(NSManagedObjectContext*) getManagedOBjectContext {
    if (_sharedInstance==nil) {
        _sharedInstance = <do create>;
     }
    return _sharedInstance;
}

///when we logout
-(IBaction) didLogout {
     <cleanup>
    _sharedInstance = nil;
}
```

This is an example of both a singleton combined with lazy loading. It will be created on demand and only once until it next gets set to nil.

Comment: Wow Thanks for the quick response.  I had read some posts about relaunching being poor practice so I'll take your advice and avoid that.  I like the accessor method better than creating the data in a didLogin method.  I need a little clarification though.  I set the `Store` to nil at logout but at what point do I call `getManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: Whenever you need it. you may call [appDelegate getManagedOBjectContext];